# Add and remove json data into object in object dynamically

Tags: javascript

i want to create a json object that store multiple object like this

```
    {
  "info": [
    {
      "id": "9861230",
      "LastPing": "hey",
      "LastPingTime": "12:30",
      "Message": [
        {
          "s_Message": "hello",
          "s_time": "01:30",
          "r_Message": "hii",
          "r_time": "01:31"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "982121",
      "LastPing": "hey",
      "LastPingTime": "12:30",
      "Message": [
        {
          "s_Message": "hello",
          "s_time": "01:30",
          "r_Message": "hii",
          "r_time": "01:31"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to create such type of json data dynamically, things that i want.
 suppose i am ping to this id = 9861230 so it will modify and add new message array in this id = 9861230 object and if there is not related id present on object then it will add new object that will contain such type of info that i have entered.

Comment: Show us some code, please. What have you tried?

Comment: "info" in your case is an array so you just have to use .push() with the new parameters. question is not very clear, can you be more specific?

Comment: actually sir i want to create an app just like whats app so i here i am facing problem to store message data into local device.

Comment: Are you facing problem adding the message to message array of a particular id in the JSON in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use id as key

```
obj = {
    "982121" : {
       "LastPing":"hey",
       "LastPingTime":"12:30",
       "Message":[
         {
           "s_Message":"hello",
           "s_time":"01:30",
           "r_Message":"hii",
           "r_time":"01:31"
         }
        ]
    }
}
```

This way you can easily add message to message array in a particular id without traversing the info array and find the object with a particular id.

```
if (obj[id]) {
    obj[id].messages.push(message);
}
else {
   obj[id] = {
       messages : []
   };
   obj[id].messages.push(message);
}
```

Comment: Line 5 should probably be `obj[id] = {`, eh?

Comment: ok and if i want to add new id with all stuff dynamically then how will i do this.

Comment: @KanishMishra `obj[newID] = newObj`